Super speed based on magnetism
Context
In my story there are several types of magic like wind magic, gravity magic, etc. My main character possesses magnetism magic which includes the ability to create strong magnetic fields on their body. They often use magnetic magic for things like railguns and telekinesis over metal objects
Question
This character needs to possess the ability to traverse across areas quickly but because they control magnetism I cannot see any direct applications that can allow them to move at high speeds. So how could somebody with the ability to create strong magnetic fields use their ability to travel at high speeds?
Edit: While I know that strong magnetic fields would cause a lot of destruction I think that collator damage should be a net positive due to rule of cool. Also the character can create magnetic fields anywhere on their body with the magnetic fields being similar to the ones featured in real life physics. The user would feel an equivalent magnetic force due to newtons third law.

Any person who drives a Tesla can travel at high speeds by depressing the acceleration pedal, which commands the creation of strong magnetic fields in the motors that drive the wheels.

Tesla magic would go crazy like imagine somebody tries to hit you with a fireball but then they get blasted by the full force of a 2 ton vehicle moving at 60 mph.

Also can you guys give me information on what I did wrong so I can fix it

There is no direct application that wouldn't have consequences. A strong enough local magnetic field that could believably (not realistically, but believably) react to a planetary magnetic field to promote flight would disrupt every form of electricity nearby - probably even brain activity. Might even magnetize the fillings in people's teeth. At that level stuff that isn't normally magnetic reacts magnetically. Now, if you want to incorporate those effects into your story.. that would be cool. Super powers should come with a price.

put your character on a railway track, apply your magnet magic and a decent portion of handwavium, and you got a maglev-train.

You say that your character can "create strong magnetic fields on their body". It would help if you could give some more detail. For instance, when the field exerts a force on an object, is an equal and opposite force applied to your character's body? Can your character manipulate the field to originate anywhere on their body, or is it treated as a whole unit? Are they bound by typical magnetic fields (that can be produced by modern science) or can they make the fields do anything they want?

Is that better?

Iron filings = reaction mass
The simplest explanation that pays even a nodding relationship to real-world physics is that the character carries a quantity of ferrous material with them and accelerates the required quantity away from them in the opposite direction to where they want to go.  Basically, they can act as a magnetic rocket engine.  This has the added bonus that it can limit the character's movements somewhat to the amount of reaction mass they are carrying, though with only moderately insane exhaust velocities a couple of kilos of iron filings would suffice for substantial journeys.  (Assuming that they can handle the acceleration on their body etc etc)
Note that this is exactly the same as the stated power that the character can act as a railgun, however, the choice of iron filings means that the exhaust will be slowed by the atmosphere over relatively short distances, rather than using larger iron slugs that would potentially kill people a long way away.  Think of it as like using a shotgun loaded with dustshot rather than buckshot - same mass, but the smaller particles are reduced to safe velocities within tens of metres at most rather than hundreds of metres.  Note also that this requires magic in order to avoid sending all the reaction mass flying away at the same time and rip all the iron out of the red blood cells in the character's body, but I'm assuming that's fine with a question tagged "magic".
If you wanto to go into an entirely "magic" system then look at Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn series, with the ability to throw out disks of metal and "push" or "pull" against them without regard to distance.  At this point, though, you may as well stop calling it magnetism and just call it telekinesis or  magic since it is ignoring the inverse squared relationship with distance that is a key element of magnetism.

How is a magnetic field going to push iron filings away from their body? A magnetic field on their body would pull the filings toward their body, not push it away. It might be different if they could create magnetic fields anywhere.

@Mathaddict given the "magic" element, they can create an extremely rapid succession of fields along the length of their body (or part thereof) in order to be a biological/magical linear accelerator.  The OP's statement that the character can act as a railgun means that they definitely can do exactly this already, they are just repurposing for propulsion rather than (intentional) destruction.  (Just like a jet aircraft or rocket, don't stand in the exhaust stream.)

@KerrAvon2055 - Hard to tell from the OP's question, but it doesn't sound like they get kickback from using their powers as a railgun, so imparting thrust from throwing away iron filings seems unlikely to work.  But throwing something tethered to you away in the direction of flight seems like it might work.  Thor's hammer, basically.  Of course, probably some problems related to dislocating one's shoulder would have to be resolved.
